# How can I rewrite my query so that functions are not being called more than once?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I an working on a regular (monthly) import of a large amount of data.  During the conversion, I am splitting a string into multiple columns, It is not just a simple split, though.  There is a little bit of logic that decides which portion of the string goes into which field.

I have written an inline function that breaks a string into multiple parts and gives you the value at a specified index.

The parameters are:

1. string value
2. delimiter
3. index

for example:

If the string value is `X4-728Z5-121-84gff` and you want the function to give you the 121, then you would call the function like this:

```
fn_MyFunc('X4-728Z5-121-84gff', '-', 3)
```

My issue is this:

In my import query, the index I need for a particular field value is dependent upon the value at another index.  If the value at index 1 = `X4` then I want index 3, else index 4.

In the single query, I call this function 4 or 5 times, depending on the result of some case statements.

The function is basically doing the same thing over and over again... but each time, I am getting a different index.  How can I reduce the efforts, such that the hard work of splitting the string is only done once, and in the same query, I can get different indexes easily?

Keep in mind that this is during an import of data from an external source, and any answer suggesting normalization or indexed views, etc will not help.

**EDIT**

I was asked to post my query:

```
SELECT
    ComplexString,
    CAST(fn_MyFunc(ComplexString, '-', 1) AS NVARCHAR(2)) AS LocationCode,
    CAST(fn_MyFunc(ComplexString, '-', 2) AS NVARCHAR(25)) AS CompanyCode,
    NULLIF(CASE
        WHEN fn_MyFunc(ComplexString, '-', 1) = 'R1' THEN NULL
        ELSE CAST(fn_MyFunc(ComplexString, '-', 3) AS INT)
    END, 0) AS ManagementType,
    CASE
        WHEN fn_MyFunc(ComplexString, '-', 1) = 'R1' THEN CAST(fn_MyFunc(ComplexString, '-', 3) AS VARCHAR(25))
        ELSE CAST(fn_MyFunc(ComplexString, '-', 4) AS NVARCHAR(25))
    END AS Network,
    .
    .
    .
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Look up indexed/materialized views.  This assumes that for the same row the index wouldn't change frequently.  Alternatively you could use function based indexes.

Comment: Out of interest why are you concerned about calling the function multiple times? I get that this could be for performance reasons but you've said this isn't a real-time operation since it occurs monthly.

Comment: mouters: You are right, but the import is run on demand by a user during business hours, and the data is quite large.  I would like to reduce the impact on other users.

Comment: @Blam: question edited to include my query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a split function the splits your string to columns and use the function in a `cross apply`.

A function to split to 5 columns could look like this.

```
alter function [dbo].[SplitString]
(
    @Value nvarchar(max),
    @Delim nchar(1)
)
returns table as return
(
    select substring(T.Value, 1, T1.P - 1) as C1,
           substring(T.Value, T1.P + 1, T2.P - T1.P - 1) as C2,
           substring(T.Value, T2.P + 1, T3.P - T2.P - 1) as C3,
           substring(T.Value, T3.P + 1, T4.P - T3.P - 1) as C4,
           substring(T.Value, T4.P + 1, T5.P - T4.P - 1) as C5
    from (select @Value+replicate(@Delim, 5)) as T(Value) 
      cross apply (select charindex(@Delim, T.Value)) as T1(P)
      cross apply (select charindex(@Delim, T.Value, T1.P + 1)) as T2(P)
      cross apply (select charindex(@Delim, T.Value, T2.P + 1)) as T3(P)
      cross apply (select charindex(@Delim, T.Value, T3.P + 1)) as T4(P)
      cross apply (select charindex(@Delim, T.Value, T4.P + 1)) as T5(P)
)
```

And it would be used like this.

```
select *
from YourTable as Y
  cross apply dbo.SplitString(Y.ColumnToSplit, '-') as S
```

The function will be called once for each row and you can use the columns `C1, C2, C3, ...` in your field list or where clause without a new call the the split function.

Comment: Thanks.  The only problem with this is that the number of parts is static.  If I have a value whose parts number less than 5 (in my case, the number of parts is variable - hence the case statements), this would raise an error.

Comment: @GabrielMcAdams That can be taken care of. Update the answer. However, you do have to decide beforehand the max number of columns you are interested in.

Comment: +1 If i have to choose.I will choose this solution.Besides running only once, Query optimizer can do optimizations as-well ,because it is a Inline Table Valued function.

Answer (score 4):

If the max of all strings is 4 parts, instead of your function you could just do this inline:

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(column, '-', '.'), 
  CASE WHEN (condition for 4th element) THEN 1 
       WHEN (condition for 3rd element) THEN 2
       WHEN (condition for 2nd element) THEN 3
       WHEN (condition for 1st element) THEN 4
   END
FROM ...
```

You could also consider:

(a) storing each portion of the string in a separate computed column. You can even persist / index the computed column.

(b) storing the separate parts of the string separately in the first place - concatenation is always easier than splitting.

**EDIT** given updated query

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT ComplexString,
         p1 = LEFT(ComplexString, 2),
         p2 = dbo.fn_MyFunc(ComplexString, '-', 2),
         p3 = dbo.fn_MyFunc(ComplexString, '-', 3),    
         p4 = dbo.fn_MyFunc(ComplexString, '-', 4)
         -- , other columns
  FROM dbo.MyTable
)
SELECT
    ComplexString,
    p1 AS LocationCode,
    LEFT(p2, 25) AS CompanyCode,
    CASE WHEN p1 <> 'RI' THEN CONVERT(INT, LEFT(p3, 3)) ELSE 0 END 
      AS ManagementType,
    LEFT(CASE WHEN p1 = 'RI' THEN p3 ELSE p4 END, 25) AS Network
FROM x;
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm familiar with that technique. There is more than 4 parts in my string.  As for your other ideas, this is during an import of a large amount of data, and the goal is to store each part separately during the data conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If the individual parts of the string are central to the operations you wish to perform on your data, an option could be to normalize further by storing the parts either as individual columns or in a related table.

Alternatively, a table valued function that returns the individual parts would enable you to improve performance if you need to access the parts many times.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I edited my question to reflect that this is during an import of data from an external source, and therefore, normalization will not help.

Answer (score 0):

If your string has a fixed (or a definite maximum) number of parts, you could create a set of variables like @part1, @part2, etc (using better names if each part has a specific meaning). Use your function to populate the variables once, and use the variables instead of re-parsing.

-- OR --

Convert your string to a narrow temp table or table variable, with one `varchar` column and one `tinyint` identity column, using a parsing method (there are a number of posts on SO on the topic - and [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#CSV)
is a nice article, geared toward csv, but easily adaptable to your situation). You can then use the sequence column in a `select` to locate the string part you need.

Comment: Your answer assumes the string only exists once. In my case, a different string exists on every row.  I cannot set a variable value for each row and use it inline.